# A Fable Problem in Calculus Class at UCLA by Doug Jungreis

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-writing

A couple of years ago, I drove up to the Bay Area, which is 400 miles, and I drove fast, so it took me five hours. At the end of the trip , I showed down, because I didn't want to get a ticket, and when when I got off the freeway, I was traveling at the speed limit. Then a police officer pulled me over, and he said, "You don't look like no Mario Andretti," an then said, "You were going a little fast there." I said I was going the speed limit, but he responded, "Maybe you were a little while ago, but earlier, you were speeding." I asked how he know that, and he said. "Son, by the mean value theorem of calculus, at some moment in the last five hours, you where going at *exactly* 80 m.p.h"

I took the ticket to court, and when push came to shove, the officer was unable to prove the mean value problem beyond a reasonable doubt.

(a) Assuming that the officer could prove the mean value theorem, would his statement have been correct? Explain.

(b) Let us change the ending of the story so that officer said , "I can't prove the mean value theorem, your Honor, but I can prove the intermediate value theorem, and using this,  "I can show that there was a time interval of exactly one minute during which the defendant drove at an average speed of 80 miles per hour. "Explain his reasoning"

Comment: Well, tell us what part of the problem you are having trouble with.

Comment: Does the officer have to prove that the car's motion was a differentiable function?

Comment: @ℝⁿ, I have problem to write the answer
@ Robert Israel, It is not completely true

Comment: "Your honor, according to Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle it's impossible to measure the car's speed precisely.  Its wave function was never an eigenfunction of momentum."  I wonder how far that would get you in court.

Comment: In other parts of the world, where they have toll roads, the intermediate value theorem is routinely used to hand out speeding tickets. They know what time you arrived at the toll gates, so they can infer information about maximum speed. If you want to drive fast, you have to stop for a while to kill time.

Comment: @bubba Is there a list of such roads? (Or could you point me to a few?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a$.  Yes, his statement would have been correct.  Let $f$ be the distance function.  Set $f(0) = 0$, and, since you arrived there in $5$ hours, $f(5) = 400$.  $f$ is continuous and differentiable (if not, that would just be plain weird), so the mean value theorem tells us that at some time $c \in [ 0 , 5 ]$

$$f'(c) = \frac{f(5) - f(0)}{5-0} = 80$$

$b$.  For $f$, let's keep it as the total distance function but have its domain correspond to each minute.  So now $f(0) = 0$ and $f(300) = 400$.  Partition $[0,300]$ into closed intervals $\left[n,n+1\right]$.  Our average speed over any time interval $[a,b]$ was $\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}$.

$\sum_{n=0}^{299} f(n+1)-f(n) = f(300) - f(0) = 400$.  So for at least two of the intervals in this partition, $[n,n+1]$ and $[m,m+1]$, $f(n+1) - f(n) \ge \frac{4}{3}$ and $f(m+1)-f(m) \le \frac{4}{3}$.

Let's create a new function $g(x) := f(x+1) - f(x)$.  $g$ corresponds to average speed over the minute following time $x$.  $g$ is also continuous, $g(n) \ge \frac{4}{3}$, and $g(m) \le \frac{4}{3}$.  By the intermediate value theorem, there exists a $c$ between $n$ and $m$ such that $g(c) = \frac{4}{3}$.  So $f(c+1) - f(c) = \frac{4}{3}$.  But this is average speed in miles per minute, so the speed in miles per hour over this interval is $\frac{4}{3} \cdot 60 = 80$.

Comment: Why Partition [0,300] not Partition [0,400]?

Comment: Because this was partitioning the domain, not the range.

Comment: Can I choose partition [0,200] or other?

Comment: Not unless you scaled your function $f$ appropriately, because $\sum f(n+1) - f(n) = 400$ would no longer hold if you took a portion of the domain.